# What is the difference between exit() and abort()?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, exit, abort

In C and C++, what is the difference between `exit()` and `abort()`? I am trying to end my program after an error (not an exception).

Answer (score 138):

[`abort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort) exits your program without calling functions registered using [`atexit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) first, and without calling objects' destructors first. [`exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) does both before exiting your program.  It does not call destructors for automatic objects though. So

```
A a;
void test() { 
    static A b;
    A c;
    exit(0);
}
```

Will destruct `a` and `b` properly, but will not call destructors of `c`. `abort()` wouldn't call destructors of neither objects. As this is unfortunate, the C++ Standard describes an alternative mechanism which ensures properly termination:

> Objects with automatic storage duration are all destroyed in a program whose function `main()` contains no automatic objects and executes the call to `exit()`. Control can be transferred directly to such a `main()` by throwing an exception that is caught in `main()`.

```
struct exit_exception { 
   int c; 
   exit_exception(int c):c(c) { } 
};

int main() {
    try {
        // put all code in here
    } catch(exit_exception& e) {
        exit(e.c);
    }
}
```

Instead of calling `exit()`, arrange that code `throw exit_exception(exit_code);` instead.

Comment: +1 because, while Brian R. Bondy was good, you did raise the problem of abort/exit (not destructor of stack objects called), and offered the alternative for a RAII-intensive C++ process.

Comment: I was looking on a way to quit a program without calling dtor and your answer is just what i was looking for! Thanks

Comment: That is perfectly correct of course, if it actually matters that your automatic objects destructors are not called :-)

Comment: To my knowledge, one further difference between exit and abort would be, that abort could (depending on the operating system configuration) lead to the generation of a core dump.

Answer (score 37):

**abort** sends a SIGABRT signal, **exit** just closes the application performing normal cleanup.

You can handle an **abort** signal however you want, but the default behavior is to close the application as well with an error code.

**abort** will not perform object destruction of your static and global members, but **exit** will.

Of course though when the application is completely closed the operating system will free up any unfreed memory and other resources.

In both **abort** and **exit** program termination (assuming you didn't override the default behavior), the return code will be returned to the parent process that started your application.

See the following example:

```
SomeClassType someobject;

void myProgramIsTerminating1(void)
{
  cout<<"exit function 1"<<endl;
}

void myProgramIsTerminating2(void)
{
  cout<<"exit function 2"<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  atexit (myProgramIsTerminating1);
  atexit (myProgramIsTerminating2);
  //abort();
  return 0;
}
```

Comments:

- If **abort** is uncommented: nothing is printed and the destructor of someobject will not be called.
- If **abort** is commented like above: someobject destructor will be called you will get the following output:

> exit function 2
>   exit function 1

Comment: Here, it called exit function 2 THEN exit function 1.  gcc 4, Linux 2.6.

Comment: Man page for atexit says: "Functions [registered using atexit] are called in reverse order; no arguments are passed."

Comment: @strager is right, the functions registered by atexit are supposed to be called in reverse order when either exit is called or main returns.

Comment: Ran a test and it appears the destructors to global instances are called after all atexit callbacks.

Comment: +1 for reminding people that the OS will eventually free-up all allocated resources even after an abort() call.

Comment: Why all the bold? Better organized into a table, imo

Answer (score 12):

The following things happen when a program calls `exit`():

- Functions registered by the `atexit` function are executed
- All open streams are flushed and closed, files created by `tmpfile` are removed
- The program terminates with the specified exit code to the host

The `abort`() function sends the `SIGABRT` signal to the current process, if it is not caught the program is terminated with no guarantee that open streams are flushed/closed or that temporary files created via `tmpfile` are removed, `atexit` registered functions are not called, and a non-zero exit status is returned to the host.

Comment: hmm. the standard says the program is only not terminated if the signal handler "does not return". you're quite well with C. can you imagine any scenario that would make it allow continue normal execution without returning? i imagine longjmp, but i'm not sure about how it behaves in signal handlers.

Comment: In general, calling longjmp from a signal handler is undefined but there is a special case for when the signal was generated with raise/abort so I guess this would be theoretically possible although I don't think I have ever seen it done.  Now I am going to have to try it ;)

Comment: This seems to work (broken into multiple posts due to 300 char limit):

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t do_abort = 1;
jmp_buf env;
void abort_handler(int i) { do_abort = 0; longjmp(env, 1);}

Comment: int main(void)
{
  setjmp(env);
  puts("At setjmp");
  if (do_abort) {
    signal(SIGABRT, abort_handler);
    puts("Calling abort");
    abort();
  }
  puts("Didn't abort!");
  return 0;
}

Comment: On Ubuntu 7.04 this prints:

At setjmp
Calling abort
At setjmp
Didn't abort!

Comment: i've seen it even support longjmp out of a SIGSEGV :) http://libsigsegv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I feel like stream flushing & closing is the most important difference. I don't care if my objects are freed by c++ dtors or the OS, but with IO this can be a big difference.

Comment: You can call [`_exit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) in the signal handler of `SIGABRT`.

Answer (score 7):

`abort` sends the `SIGABRT` signal.  `abort` does not return to the caller.  The default handler for the `SIGABRT` signal closes the application.  `stdio` file streams are flushed, then closed.  Destructors for C++ class instances are not, however (not sure on this one -- perhaps results are undefined?).

`exit` has its own callbacks, set with `atexit`.  If callbacks are specified (or only one), they are called in the order reverse of their registration order (like a stack), then the program exits.  As with `abort`, `exit` does not return to the caller.  `stdio` file streams are flushed, then closed.  Also, destructors for C++ class instances are called.

Comment: exit can have multiple callback functions registered via atexit, when exit is called all the callback functions will be called in the reverse order in which they were registered.

Comment: @Gamble, Of course, I mentioned that myself a few minutes ago in a comment to @Bondy's answer.  I'll edit my own answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

From the exit() manual page:

> The  exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of
>   status & 0377 is returned to the parent.

From the abort() manual page:

> The  abort()  first  unblocks  the SIGABRT signal, and then raises that
>   signal for the calling process.  This results in the abnormal  termination  of the process unless the SIGABRT signal is caught and the signal
>   handler does not return.