# Mac OS X equivalent for TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess,0);

Tags: c++, macos, terminate

I am looking for a simple and uncatchable way to terminate the Mac port of my C++ application. In Windows I was using

```
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, 0);
```

What's the equivalent command I can use with Mac OS X / XCode / GCC?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397075/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-abort

Comment: Just for reference, Windows _exit() does some cleanup before calling ExitProcess(). I assume exit() is the same but with some extended cleanup code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you want `_exit` if you want to have the same semantics as `TerminateProcess`. `exit` semantics are more closely aligned with `ExitProcess`.

Answer (score 3):

A closer to [ProcessTerminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx) will be to send a [SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) with [kill](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DARWIN/Reference/ManPages/man2/kill.2.html), both terminate the current process immediately and can't be trapped. This is the same as [_exit](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DARWIN/Reference/ManPages/man2/_exit.2.html)

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

Comment: Or, a bit easier: `raise(SIGKILL)`.

Answer (score 1):

exit(0);

---

Comment: exit is more like ExitProcess which tries to shutdown the application cleanly, but it might fail. TerminateProces is unconditional and can't be trapped.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if either you call exit() or TerminateProcess(), you'll get you application terminated immediately, i.e. no destructor calls, no cleanup you may expect to be done is done (of course OS cleans up everything it can).

Comment: exit will call the functions registered with atexit, so it is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, both exit() and _exit() involve the CRT, which means various actions are still taken. (Not sure about atexit, I haven't checked)

TerminateProcess on Windows is on the OS level, so it sidesteps all of the CRT. If you want to do the same thing on the Mac, your best bet is getting your hands dirty with mach functions. In this case:

```
#include <mach/mach.h>

... // lots of your code here

task_terminate(mach_task_self());
```

That's about as uncatchable as you can get.