# C how to handle malloc returning NULL? exit() or abort()

Tags: c

When malloc() fails, which would be the best way to handle the error? If it fails, I want to immediately exit the program, which I would normally do with using exit(). But in this special case, I'm not quite sure if exit() would be the way to go here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between exit() and abort()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397075/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-abort)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In library code, it's absolutely unacceptable to call `exit` or `abort` under any circumstances except when the caller broke the contact of your library's documented interface. If you're writing library code, you should gracefully handle any allocation failures, freeing any memory or other resources acquired in the attempted operation and returning an error condition to the caller. The calling program may then decide to `exit`, `abort`, reject whatever command the user gave which required excessive memory, free some unneeded data and try again, or whatever makes sense for the application.

In all cases, if your application is holding data which has not been synchronized to disk and which has some potential value to the user, you should make every effort to ensure that you don't throw away this data on allocation failures. The user will almost surely be **very angry**. It's best to design your applications so that the "save" function does not require any allocations, but if you can't do that in general, you might instead want to perform frequent auto-save-to-temp-file operations or provide a way of dumping the memory contents to disk in a form that's not the standard file format (which might for example require ugly XML and ZIP libraries, each with their own allocation needs, to write) but instead a more "raw dump" which you application can read and recover from on the next startup.

Comment: Well if the user has consumed all available system memory and swap space they can hardly be angry about hard failures. That's like blaming the application programmer when the power fails.

Comment: A robust system gives you plenty of time to save when the power fails. Even if it's just a laptop, if it's not junk you should have 4-10 hours...

Answer (score 5):

If `malloc()` returns `NULL` it means that the allocation was unsuccessful. It's up to you to deal with this error case. I personally find it excessive to exit your entire process because of a failed allocation. Deal with it some other way.

Comment: I think this depends on the application.  If you were writing an editor, for example, I would agree with you.  You should at least try to save open files, maybe to a backup file.  However, a number crunching application may not be able to do anything useful if it cannot allocate enough memory.  In that case, logging a useful error and exiting may be the best that you can do.

Comment: Indeed it really depends on the application. A simple media player (without any music download/purchase/playlist/library functionality) would be perfectly justified in just exiting on allocation failures. But a word processor or web browser that exits (and possibly loses the user's research paper, partially-written blog post/comment, email, etc. in the process) would draw a lot of anger from users.

Comment: Furthermore, when do modern application have failing allocations? Only when the system is running amok and no memory nor swap space is left in the system (imagine a memory leaking fork bomb). So crashing the program the fastest as possible is not a bad idea in that case.

Comment: I can think of plenty mathematical applications that might have failing allocations. For example if the user typed `print 3!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!` (`!` meaning factorial) in a calculator with arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Now make it not just a calculator but a numeric analyst's research environment, and enjoy the hatemail you get when someone types an expression like that "just for fun" without first saving their work, and loses everything. (P.S. If your app is based on GMP, that's exactly what will happen...)

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Both?

---

It depends on whether the core file will be useful. If no one is going to analyze it, then you  may as well simply `_exit(2)` or `exit(3)`.

If the program will sometimes be used locally and you intend to analyze any core files produced, then that's an argument for using `abort(3)`.

You could always choose conditionally, so, with `--debug` use `abort(3)` and without it use exit.

Comment: Recommend against `_exit()` as that means that cleanup functions registered with `atexit()` won't run...