# Memory Leak with no dynamic memory

Tags: c++, memory, vector, dynamic, memory-leaks

I was wondering if you you could have a memory leak on the heap without having any dynamic memory allocated. However, I do have three vectors declared and initialized. Is it because I need to deallocate the vector before I close the program.

[image: Valgrind]

Comment: You don't need to deallocate the vectors.  You should post your code that generated those results.

Comment: `vector`'s destructor will deal with the deallocation for you. Can we see some of the code?

Comment: Vectors allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Copy paste the error instead of attaching the image. That way people can google your problem easily and hopefully help you

Answer (score 3):

I just found the problem, it was the exit function that I was using to close the program.

> exit does not call the destructors of any stack based objects so if those objects have allocated any memory internally then yes that memory will be leaked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7414211/6284032